# cant redirect rsync error to stdout

Tags: rsync

Hi everyone the following works fine

```bsh
rsync -r -e "ssh -i /key/file.ssh/" name@server.org:/remote/place /local/place/
```

but the following

```bsh
rsync -r -e "ssh -i /key/file.ssh/" name@server.org:/remote/place /local/place/ 2>&1 /some/local/place/log.txt
```

produces

```bsh
Unexpected local arg: /rds/PRJ-InsulinAnalogs/gadi_backup/
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1215) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error

Comment: Did you intend to write `>/some/local/place/log.txt 2>&1`? as it stands, you're redirecting errors to stdout, but not redirecting `stdout` to your log file